# Avoiding Consecutive Buy and Sell Signals ( I checked all previous avoiding AA and BB related questions but could not solve my issue)

Tags: pine-script

I have been trying to eliminate consecutive Buy and Sell signals. I read all related posts and came up with below strategy. But it does not work :( if anyone knows how to solve my issue and give me a hand I would appreciate very very much. Many thanks in advance

When first Buy signal is created I expect my code to turn "Longposition" variable to true and then I expect to avoid from consecutive Buy signals. But it does not seem to work

```
//@version = 4
study("openclosedelta", shorttitle="openclosedelta", overlay=true)

closeconf = security(symbol=syminfo.tickerid, resolution="30", expression=close, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
openconf = security(symbol=syminfo.tickerid, resolution="30",expression=open, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

Longposition = false
Shortposition = false


Buy =   open>close[1] and open[1]>close[2]
Buyconf = openconf>closeconf[1] and openconf[1]>closeconf[2]
    
Sell =  open<close[1] and open[1]<close[2]
Sellconf = openconf<closeconf[1] and openconf[1]<closeconf[2]


Long = Longposition==false and Buy or Buyconf

Short = Shortposition==false and Sell or Sellconf

if Long==true
    Longposition := true
    Shortposition := false
   
    
if Short==true
    Shortposition := true
    Longposition := false
    


plotshape(Long ,"AL", text="BUY", location=location.belowbar, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white)
plotshape(Short ,"SAT", text="SELL", location=location.abovebar, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you forgot to initialize

```
Longposition = false
Shortposition = false
```

as `var` variables, which will allow to store its values between bars.

Second, your `Buy` or `Buyconf` still might to set your `Long` condition to `true` as it used with `or` operator such as

```
Long = Longposition==false and Buy or Buyconf

Short = Shortposition==false and Sell or Sellconf
```

instead of

```
Long = Longposition==false and (Buy or Buyconf)

Short = Shortposition==false and (Sell or Sellconf)
```

```
//@version = 4
study("openclosedelta", shorttitle="openclosedelta", overlay=true)

closeconf = security(symbol=syminfo.tickerid, resolution="30", expression=close, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
openconf = security(symbol=syminfo.tickerid, resolution="30",expression=open, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

var Longposition = false
var Shortposition = false


Buy =   open>close[1] and open[1]>close[2]
Buyconf = openconf>closeconf[1] and openconf[1]>closeconf[2]
    
Sell =  open<close[1] and open[1]<close[2]
Sellconf = openconf<closeconf[1] and openconf[1]<closeconf[2]


Long = Longposition==false and (Buy or Buyconf)

Short = Shortposition==false and (Sell or Sellconf)

if Long==true
    Longposition := true
    Shortposition := false
   
    
if Short==true
    Shortposition := true
    Longposition := false
    


plotshape(Long ,"AL", text="BUY", location=location.belowbar, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white)
plotshape(Short ,"SAT", text="SELL", location=location.abovebar, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white)
```

Comment: Starr Lucky, you are my hero :) if you ever come to Turkey, just let me know... Fish and Rakı by the Bosphorus is on me :)